# Unix Loop through files, grab specific text in the files and create new files with those lines only

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I have folder that contains about a 100 files.  I want to search for a specific word in each file, pick up only those lines from each file and put them in separate files.  For example:

Look for lines that contain the word "HELLO" (case-sensitive) in FILE1.txt, FILE2.txt, FILE3.txt.

```
From FILE1, copy those lines and put them in a new file, FILE1_BK.txt
From FILE2, copy those lines and put them in a new file, FILE2_BK.txt
From FILE3, copy those lines and put them in a new file, FILE3_BK.txt
```

I know how to do this one file at a time but am unable to write the script for multiple files at once.

```
grep "HELLO" FILE1.txt > FILE1_BK.txt
```

Need to incorporate it in the loop.

```
for f in myFolder; do something; done;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why loop through it manually? Why not `grep "HELLO" *.txt > FILE1_BK.txt` ?

```
for f in *.txt; do
    grep "HELLO" $f > $f_found.txt;
done
```

Comment: I need to put them in separate files. FILE1.txt to FILE1_BK.txt and FILE2.txt in FILE2_BK.txt.  I need to keep the same number of files and not just one file that contains lines containing that word from the 100 files. Hence, something like for f in myFolder; do something; done;

Comment: I figured it out: 

for f in ./myFolder/*; do grep "SEARCHWORD" $f > $f.bak; done;

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have filepaths stored in a file named **filenames.txt** Then you can do:

```
while read -r filepath; do
    grep -r "pattern" $filepath > "$filepath""-output"
done < filenames.txt
```

This obviously assumes all filepaths are in new lines in **filenames.txt**

Answer (score 0):

for f in ./myFolder/*; do grep "SEARCHWORD" $f > $f.bak; done;